# join information of two dataframes R

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I'd like to join two dataframes with R
here the first one

```
   resno resid elety eleno
    1     ILE     C     3
    1     ILE     O     4
    2     VAL     C    11
    2     VAL     O    12
    3     GLY     C    18
    3     GLY     O    19
```

the second one

```
   C.O     dist
  12-18   3.112819
  27-37   2.982788
  51-63   3.185184
  52-62   2.771583
  63-69   3.157737
  70-80   2.956738
```

so let's explain what i need. Looking at the second dataframe, i have distance ("dist") between points 12-18, corresponding to "eleno" in the first dataframe. for this 2 points I have also "resno" that is what i'm interesting in, because i'd like to obtain something like this

```
       resno resid elety eleno rescoup   dist
        1     ILE     C     3     -       -
        1     ILE     O     4     -       -
        2     VAL     C    11     -       -
        2     VAL     O    12    2-3   3.112819
        3     GLY     C    18    2-3   3.112819
        3     GLY     O    19     -       -
```

how can I do? is this possible with R?

thanks!

Comment: Is 12-18 a range? or 2 fixed numbers, ie. would eleno=13 match with 12-18 too, or not?

Comment: no, fixed numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first create a long dataframe from `df2` where every number from `C.O` is a unique row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  separate(C.O, c('col1', 'col2'), sep = '-', convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(eleno = purrr::map2(col1, col2, seq), .before = 1, 
         row = row_number()) %>%
  select(-col1, -col2) %>%
  unnest(eleno)

df3
# A tibble: 60 x 3
#   eleno   row  dist
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1    12     1  3.11
# 2    13     1  3.11
# 3    14     1  3.11
# 4    15     1  3.11
# 5    16     1  3.11
# 6    17     1  3.11
# 7    18     1  3.11
# 8    27     2  2.98
# 9    28     2  2.98
#10    29     2  2.98
# … with 50 more rows
```

Join this dataframe with `df1` and `paste` `resno` values to create `rescoup`.

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df3, by = 'eleno') %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(rescoup = paste(resno, collapse = '-'), 
         rescoup = replace(rescoup, is.na(dist), NA)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)

#  resno resid elety eleno  dist rescoup
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl> <chr>  
#1     1 ILE   C         3 NA    NA     
#2     1 ILE   O         4 NA    NA     
#3     2 VAL   C        11 NA    NA     
#4     2 VAL   O        12  3.11 2-3    
#5     3 GLY   C        18  3.11 2-3    
#6     3 GLY   O        19 NA    NA
```

Comment: I don't understand 2 things: 1- why did you do the first step? i don't have a range, they're fixed numbers. 2. %>% what this symbols means? I'm new on R, sorry

Comment: Yes but expanding the range is one way to perform this otherwise we can't join directly on the range (12-18). `%>%` is a pipe symbol which is commonly used with `tidyverse` package.

Comment: okay, I understand. But copying your code i got this error: Problem with `mutate()` input `eleno`.
x 'map2' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyr'
i Input `eleno` is `tidyr::map2(col1, col2, seq)`.

Comment: Sorry `map2` is from `purrr`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using *data.table*, split then merge:

```
library(data.table)

merge(d1,
      d2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, "-", fixed = TRUE,
                                                    type.convert = TRUE)))],
      by.x = "eleno", by.y = "C.O", all.x = TRUE)

#    eleno resno resid elety     dist
# 1:     3     1   ILE     C       NA
# 2:     4     1   ILE     O       NA
# 3:    11     2   VAL     C       NA
# 4:    12     2   VAL     O 3.112819
# 5:    18     3   GLY     C 3.112819
# 6:    19     3   GLY     O       NA
```

Example data:

```
d1 <-   fread("resno resid elety eleno
1     ILE     C     3
1     ILE     O     4
2     VAL     C    11
2     VAL     O    12
3     GLY     C    18
3     GLY     O    19")
d2 <- fread("C.O     dist
12-18   3.112819
27-37   2.982788
51-63   3.185184
52-62   2.771583
63-69   3.157737
70-80   2.956738")
```

Comment: coping your code and using names of my df I got this error: "Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'"

Comment: @Nancy This works fine with the example data in this answer.

Comment: idk what's going wrong in my script. dataframes I'd like to merge were created on R reading a file. I think the problem is that I have to transform my dataframe columns in vector, is this possible?